# Running all flutter unit tests from Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter, flutter-test

I used to be able to run all my Flutter unit tests from the Android Studio GUI by right clicking on the tests directory and clicking on "Run 'tests in my_app'". After deleting and recloning my app directory (and maybe along with a combination of something else), I see this in the run log after attempting to run the tests:

```
Testing started at 8:42 AM ...
C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\pub.bat run test -r json C:/Users/me/AndroidStudioProjects/my_app
Observatory listening on http://127.0.0.1:2397/S0P_H2wKVSE=/

The Flutter SDK is not available.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

My SDK is setup properly because I can run and debug the app from Android Studio. If I run `flutter test` from the terminal tab in AS, the tests are executed successfully.

Answer (score 13):

Good question,
I haven't found an answer yet, but I was able to define a new run configuration to run all my tests that were under "test" directory.

**menu**-->**Run**-->**Edit configurations**

Add a new configurations --> **Flutter Test**

Configuration:
Test scope: **All in directory**
Test directory: <*your test directory*>.
*For example on my ubuntu: /home/MyUser/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApp/test*

Comment: Would be nice to have an example of that <your test directory> :) How do you specify relative path to tests..

Answer (score 0):

I want to edit the previous question, but I can't, so I just write it here

basically you need to change **Test Scope** to **All in directory**

Steps

1. Create New Configuration: **Flutter Test**

[image: New Flutter Test Configuration]

2. Change the configuration

**Test Scope** to change to **All in directory**

**Test Directory** to **your root project**

example

[image]

That's it!